# Bootstrap 4 Grid - rows aren't the same length

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a Bootstrap 4 Grid. I've noticed that if I set a `max-width` on the container, the rows become uneven in length.

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px !important;
}

.purple-row [class^="col"] {
  background-color: rgba(232, 179, 254, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(232, 179, 254, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row purple-row">
    <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
    <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row purple-row">
    <div class="col">col-4</div>
    <div class="col">col-4</div>
    <div class="col">col-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this? Are the column `flex-basis` percentages not exact? Maybe it's something simple I'm missing, but I appreciate the help here.

Here is a [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/odzwaw) to experiment with this.

Bootstrap 4 lets you set the container `max-width` via its `$container-max-widths` variable. However when I do this, I get the problem I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **second row** has classes called `col`, whereas the **first row** has classes called `col-8` and `col-4`. By simply making the other col's also col-4's, it solves the problem: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t12ghsy9/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a consequence of using percentage max-widths for the elements. I was able to solve the problem by adding the following CSS:

```
.purple-row [class^="col"] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```